# pgfplots: Forcing Scientific Notation for y Axis

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I wish to force PGFPlots to use the same scientific notation exponent for all y tick labels, with the exponent placed above the graph, turning this style

[image]

into this style

[image]

I'm currently using `scaled y ticks = true` with no effect. I'm aware I could use `scaled y ticks=base 10:2` to manually specify to use 1E2, but I'm looking for a more general solution.

Comment: Can you post the script you used to generate the first graph above?

Comment: Is your problem solved? If not then please at least leave a feedback.

Answer (score 3):

I assume that you are looking for `y tick label style={/pgf/number format/sci}`. See also Chapter 4.13.1 **(Frequently Used Number Printing Settings**) in the current `pgfplots` manual ( I find it a bit difficult for beginners since this is `tikz` stuff as I understand it and not `pgfplots` -specific), see also* manual of `pgfplotstable` Chapter 2.7 (**Number Formatting Options**).

> I do not know how to get the common `mantissa` sepearte from the
>   ticks and at the top of the axis: Any experts here?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}

% Based on http://pgfplots.sourceforge.net/gallery.html
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        xlabel=$x$,
        ylabel={$f(x) = x^2 - x +4$},
        % Added
        y tick label style={/pgf/number format/sci},
    ]
    % use TeX as calculator:
    \addplot {x^2 - x +4};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

*<sub>"The options related to number printing as such are described in all detail in the manual for PgfplotsTable,
which comes with pgfplots."</sub>

[image]